# Last part of string not getting inserted into coredata

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-data

I am trying to insert the last part of a string in Core Data store. I am getting the string using `NSXMLParser` but the last part of the string does not get inserted.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *fields in [delegate forecastConditions]) {
           // NSLog(@"got %@", fields);
            NSNumber*high=[fields objectForKey:@"high"];
            NSLog(@"the high is %@",high);
            NSManagedObjectContext *new=[self managedObjectContext];
            NSManagedObject *newNote;
            newNote=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Weather" inManagedObjectContext:new];
            [newNote setValue:[fields valueForKey:@"high"] forKey:@"high"];
            NSNumber *low=[fields objectForKey:@"low"];
            NSLog(@"the low is %@",low);
            [newNote setValue:[fields valueForKey:@"low"] forKey:@"low"];
            NSString*icon=[fields objectForKey:@"icon"];
            NSString *all=[icon lastPathComponent];

            NSLog(@" the icon is %@",all);
             [newNote setValue:[fields valueForKey:@"all"] forKey:@"condition"];
            NSString *string=[fields objectForKey:@"condition"];
            NSLog(@"the condition is %@",string);
            [newNote setValue:[fields valueForKey:@"string"] forKey:@"state"];

        }
```

Comment: What `newNote` keyname out of  high, low, condition or state, is not being set?

Comment: Does the `fields` dictionary actually have a `string` key or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Your code excerpt is too short for us to determine what the problem is, but your mixing of `[fields objectForKey:]` and `[fields valueForKey:]` rings alarm bells.